# Using named ranged in google sheets as variables in custom formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Not sure if this is going to make sense but here I go.

What I want to do is to create a formula that isn't linked to a cell directly. In example: if I want to calculate carryweight for a tabletop game like D&D I would need the formula (strengthBonus x 5). For my current attempt I renamed the range (cell rather) strengthBonus to MOD_STR so when I put the formula =(multiply(MOD_STR,5) it works like a charm. Then I named that range "CARRYWEIGHT" and then use it elsewhere.

What I would like to be able to do is to make a new variable, similar to the way that "Define Named Range" does, but instead of relying on the variables being somewhere on the spreadsheet they would process from an internal formula. For example, if I type =carryweight into a cell it would run the equation =MULTIPLY(MOD_STR,5) in that cell and output the answer. I know nothing about code yet but have just been pointed in the direction of tutorials but I'm also asking for help here.

The code I have tried is

```
function CARRYWEIGHT(MOD_STR){
return MOD_STR*2}
```

and something else, I can't remember what but I got it to at least accept it in the spreadsheet. When I type it in I get an error stating that the outcome isn't a number.

I have no idea where to go from here.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- The difference between sheets formulas and Apps Script is that in Apps Script you  need to retrieve the value of the range corresponding to the name of a named range
- You cannot simply multiply the name of the range (which is a string!) with a number

### Here is a sample of how to retrieve a range by name and make calculations wiht the value stored in it:

```
function CARRYWEIGHT(MOD_STR){
  // retrieve all named ranges in the spreadsheet
  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges();
  //loop through all the results
  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++){
    var range = namedRanges[i];
    //if the range with the name equal to the value of MOD_STR is found, get the cell content of this range
    if(range.getName()==MOD_STR){
      var value = range.getRange().getValue();
      // perform the calculation with the cell content of the named range
      return value*2;
    }  
  }
}
```

From the cell, call the function as `=CARRYWEIGHT("paste here the name of the range of interest")`, do not forget the quotes (unless it is a cell reference)!

I hope this helped you to get started, for further understanding plese consult the following references.

### References

- [Named Ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range)
- [Loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)
- [Conditional statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)
- [Ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

Comment: So my function would be CARRYWEIGHT(STR_MOD)? is there a way that the function can be JUST "CARRYWEIGHT" without the "(var)" part? Its okay if not. Which part would I have to repeat for multiple named ranges to be in the final product?

Comment: Additionally, when I use the above code, it might work, but it doesn't display the value output in a cell if I just put (=CARRYWEIGHT(MOD_STR). I may have done something wrong.

Comment: What is `MOD_STR`? Is it the name of a named range? In this case you have to call it with quotes: `=CARRYWEIGHT("MOD_STR")`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: Is is possible to add "CARRYWEIGHT"  as a stand alone variable that is equal to the above function? So that it doesn't even need parentheses? Or is that far too complicated? I mean treating it as if it was a named range but without needing the helper cells?

Comment: It is possible without parathensis if you always want to retrieve a range with the same name and you know in advance what is the name of this range.